# How to find the protocolbuf specification of binary format?

Tags: protocol-buffers

How i can find the specification of `protocolbuf`?

I've only found a draft with few informations at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-rfernando-protocol-buffers-00#section-1

But i wan't a specification of the binary format, how the data is composed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

Note that the *encoding* specification is unchanged between proto2 and proto3; only the DSL and API change between those.